# Vim and NERD tree - deleting a file

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Is there an easy way to delete a file under the cursor in Vim NERDTree?

Toggling help `?` doesn't show any mappings for deleting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use <kbd>m</kbd> to open the menu, then <kbd>d</kbd> (or scroll down to delete and press enter). <kbd>Esc</kbd> exits the menu if you changed your mind.

Comment: How do I suppress the warning? I don't want to type `y` every time.